# Javascript - downloading a file using Iframe and then removing it

Tags: javascript, iframe

What I want to do is:

1. Append a new iframe to the body and download a file using it.
2. Remove the iframe once the file is downloaded..

I read a few posts and came up with this code:

```
let fileHref = baseLocation + '/excelexports/' + fileName;
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display = "none";
iframe.src = fileHref;
iframe.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);    
};
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

The problem is the `onload` callback is not firing after the file is downloaded...

Comment: onload is for the DOM load, it knows nothing about a file download state.  Simple solution is not to remove the iframe at all.  If you need to use it again create it with an id only if that id does not already exist thus ensuring you only do it once.

Comment: There is no such event for a download.

Comment: @AlexK. your correct and wrong at the same time, the DOM load is correct however you don't need the download state once the download has started the browser has connection and the iframe can be removed however where you are correct is in knowing if the iframe has triggered the download is impossible as the iframe onload wont fire as it's not loaded a page via the browser engine responsible for firing javascript

Comment: but the problem is that i am making the dom messy with many iframes :{

Comment: So only create one: `var ifr  = document.getElementById("hidden_iframe"); if (!ifr) ifr = createIFrameFunc(); ifr.src = ...;`

Comment: Yea, thats what I'll do, thx

Comment: I just try to remove the iframe after 60 seconds. It seems work.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use an iframe at all. Just do a redirect to the download url. The headers in the url will prevent the browser from loading that as a page and therefore not destroying the current page

```
let fileHref = baseLocation + '/excelexports/' + fileName;
window.location.href  = fileHref ;
```

Comment: The problem which got me to use an iframe is that with your solution AdBlockers can block that call, I want to pass through that

Comment: @omriman12 Most will only block that call if it is not triggered from a user action event most popup blockers now are tied into the core of the javascript engine of the browser E.G Built into the browser and these will block downloads that are not triggered by user events and rightly so. the fact that your able to trigger via iframe without user action is a bug in the popup blocker that no doubt will be fixed.

Comment: this now doesn't work with Chrome 65 https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/chrome-65-deprecations

Comment: Small note (probably not important). This will trigger any "onbeforeunload" events even though the page won't actually unload (unless the target href doesn't actually trigger a download). This does still work for same origin downloads as well

Comment: Does not work on Brave 1.62.156. The browser hides the current page and open a download dialog. If the user downloads the file or (cancels the download) a blank page is displayed.

Answer (score 3):

you could just use the HTML5 download attribute. E.G `<a href='{fileurl}' download>download</a>`
or if you need the javascript engine to do it.

```
let fileHref = baseLocation + '/excelexports/' + fileName;
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.setAttribute("download", true);
anchor.setAttribute("href", fileHref);
anchor.click();
```

If your using a click to run this javascript you can even pass though the event to help identify your download as a user action to more intrusive popup blockers.

```
someElem.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
    let fileHref = baseLocation + '/excelexports/' + fileName;
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.setAttribute("download", true);
    anchor.setAttribute("href", fileHref);
    anchor.dispatchEvent(evt);
});
```

source: 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
Below code might help someone who is looking to download file using iframe-

with(document){
                ir=createElement('iframe');
                ir.id='ifr';
                ir.location='about.blank';
                ir.style.display='none';
                body.appendChild(ir);
                with(getElementById('ifr').contentWindow.document){
                    open("text/plain", "replace");
                    charset = "utf-8";
                    write("---WELCOME ---");
                   document.charset = "utf-8";
                  popupHtml = 
              document.getElementById('ifr').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;;
                    download(filename+'.txt', popupHtml);
}

function download(filename, text) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).